# User UTF-8 string in ConTeXt

Tags: luatex, unicode, context-mkiv

I need to use input from a JSON inside my text. Sometimes it contains UTF-8 code. For example:

```
Belgi\u00e
cre\u00ebren
```

How can I use such string in ConTeXt LuaTeX, so the result is a correctly spelled Dutch word?

```
België
creëren
```

Preferably, as part of a sentence, where the %placeofbirthCandidate and %raisedinCountries are replaced by the content of the JSON.

```
\par Je bent geboren in %placeofbirthCandidate. Je bent opgegroeid in %raisedinCountries. 

\par Je bent geboren in Belgi\"e. Je bent opgegroeid in Nederland, Belgi\"e en Engeland.
```

Comment: note the javascript/JSON `\u` code is UTF-16 code points not UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the matter and ask why they said UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need characters below `\ua000` then you can presumably use

```
\def\u#1#2#3#4{\uchar"#1#2#3#4 }
```

If you need to use higher characters with a letter following `\u` then you could in addition make u a non-letter

```
\catcode`\u=12
```

but best to do that in a local group or something will break.

(This is just using luatex primitives so should work in context.)

Note that characters between U+FFFF and U+10FFFF would be represented in JSON by two `\u` sequences denoting the UTF-16 encoding of the unicode value, so a complete solution would have to detect the first of a UTF-16 surrogate pair and combine with the following `\u` code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will consult this with our team and start testing.